# How to make a two-point perspective render?

Tags: rendering

[**Two-point perspective**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_%28graphical%29#Two-point_perspective) render is very popular for rendering architectures. In Yafaray, there is an [*Architect Camera*](http://www.yafaray.org/documentation/userguide/objects#Architect) to do this.

Is there any way to achieve this in BI and/or Cycles?

Comment: For BI or Cycles?

Comment: May I know both, if possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems this is not possible to do the same way as Yafaray, however you can do it with camera positioning and tweaking the *Shift* values.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Camera/Perspective#Two_Point_Rendering):

> ## Two Point Rendering
>
> Normal architectural
>   rendering is called two point rendering; when vertical lines are
>   parallel, and horizontals, if followed out to the side, converge on
>   one point, and receding or depth lines converge to a second point.
>
> Architects often like this Two-Point rendering, so that the sides of
>   their buildings are completely vertical and don't appear to be falling
>   inward. This is also quite nice for compositions and schematics, given
>   that the lines of the paper you print on and the screen you view with
>   are also straight.
>
> Previously to get a 2-point perspective, you had to
>   aim the camera level to the horizon, however this resulted in the top
>   half of the building being cut off and the horizon being in the exact
>   middle, which looks very boring. Architectural photographers use
>   'shift lenses' to solve this problem. Shift lenses shift the image to
>   another place on the film. Two Point Horizontal Render This technique
>   works well for high buildings as well as for normal sized objects.
>
> Most of the time, the two vanishing points are horizontal and depth
>   lines, with the vertical lines parallel. However, some titles are done
>   with the horizontal lines parallel, and the vertical and depth lines
>   having the vanishing point. This dramatizes and exaggerates the
>   massiveness and height of the title.
>
> To get this effect, position the camera at ground level, centered,
>   angle the camera upward, and shift the render passpartout down. In the
>   example, the camera is rotated 30 degrees upward, at ground level with
>   the title. A bright key light with a short falloff provides dramatic
>   lighting that is bright in the middle and falls off toward the sides,
>   further enhancing the depth.
>
> ### To achieve 2-point rendering:
>
> - Use a short wide angle lens camera, say with a Lens Size of 10 mm placed close to the building, or a long lens farther away from the
>     building. These differences affect the depth of the building render,
>     with longer lenses making the building appear thinner and less
>     dramatic or distorted. The example uses a 40mm lens.
> - Position the camera off to one side of the object, vertically halfway up the building to minimize distortion of the vertical
>     building edges. You may alter this vertical (Z value) position to be
>     slightly higher than ground level or higher than the top (if you want
>     to see the top of the object or building). To show the front bottom
>     corner of the building jutting out, raise up the camera.
> - Angle the camera to be looking away from the building and directly level at the horizon - not pointed up or down (note the 20 degree Z
>     angle in the example). This should make the vertical lines parallel.
>     The more the camera looks at the object, the closer the vanishing
>     point for the horizontal lines, and perceived depth will increase as
>     that vanishing point gets closer as well.
> - You may have to angle the camera slightly down (just 1 degree or so) so that vertical lines appear vertically up and down, both near
>     and far. If the lines are curved, use a longer lens. With your 3D View
>     set to Camera view, use the passpartout or pixels on your monitor to
>     determine vertical.
> - Move the camera toward/away from the object until it appears near a corner of the render and is the right size.
> - Adjust the Shift: X and Y settings until your object is positioned properly.

E.g.:

With a normal camera setup:

[image]

With the camera setup as described in the wiki:

[image]