# How can I set a custom projection matrix for rendering?

Tags: rendering, camera

How can I set a camera projection matrix? I want to render a perspective like the old SimCity 1989:

[image: image description]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5183/how-to-make-a-two-point-perspective-render?, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1888/how-can-i-get-a-cabinet-projection-camera?rq=1

Comment: Great! Thanks very much! Please tell me how yu find the angles (curious how find them).

Comment: For my answer below I just eyeballed it based on the image you linked to.

Comment: This not correct, is close but not correct. x and y direction lines not 90°. In blender picture look close, x grid lines almost horizontal but not horizontal, y lines OK.

Comment: I think I need matrix like this or transpose (assume no translation, no scale, no rotation):
{x_c, y_c, z_c, w_c} =  {x_w, y_w, z_w_, w_w} × {{1,  0,  0,  0}, {0,  1, 0,  0}, {ส,  ส,  1  0 }, {0  0  1, 0}, {0  0  0  1}}
Subscript w is world coordinate, c is camera, ส is scale for project z direction to x and y axises.

Comment: I am looking to do the exact same projection but simply cannot find any answers. did you end up finding a solution to this? thanks.

Comment: @mrcavallo No solution yet. I still try find way use python for loading a matrix. I have correct matrix (show in comment above) but need way load inside camera matrix!

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23572

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For orthographic rendering Blender **can't** take a custom projection matrix, however you **can** shear an orthographic projection to get the desired results.

- Use an orthographic camera, with the camera set at an angle (45 degrees on the `X` and `Z` axis).
- In the render settings, set the **Aspect X** to `sqrt(2)`
  *This will give something almost exactly what you're looking for, except that its rotated 45 degrees*.
- To correct the rotation, use the compositors **Distort -> Transform** node.

[image]

Notes:

- rotating the image will loose some accuracy, so you'll want to render larger, then scale down.
- in the compositor you can scale down by `1/sqrt(2)` to avoid loosing the corners.
- Depth/Mist won't work as you might want, however its probably possible to use a gradient and offset the depth in the compositor.

Comment: Excellent work! Use rotation –45° for SimCity direction.

Comment: Careful, x and y direction ok; but z direction is not correct for mist or depth effects.

Comment: @Châu good point, noted in answer.