# How to set a custom 4x4 projection matrix in Blender

Tags: python, rendering, camera

I have seen some questions to this topic but all of them are not satisfactory for my problem.
Is it possible to set a custom 4x4 projection matrix in Python to use for rendering in Blender? I'm not interested to manipulate single parameters (lens, shift, clipping...), I rather would like to set the whole matrix at once. Is it possible in Python or do I have to go deeper?

I would be so thankful for any informations or hints.

greetings

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6810/599

Answer (score 5):

A camera object, [bpy.types.Camera](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.Camera.html), does not expose a matrix property or anything similar. You can only change the available properties, which should be equal to what you can do via the user interface in the *Object data* tab.

Comment: And do you know where I can actually manipulate the projection matrix?

Comment: Somewhere around here: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/render/intern/

Comment: Actually, its "exposed" in terms of reading it, heres how you read intrinsics and extrinsics... https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20231 But still looking how to set them, its probably not an one-liner, but have to do it using sensor etc...