# How to compute image coordinates from projection matrix?

Tags: scripting, image

I get the projection matrix from the Camera object (projection_matrix) and it is a 4x4 matrix. I have an object in the scene whose "worldPosition" is known (x,y,z). Now I want to project the 3D point (x,y,z) to an image using projection_matrix. My question is how can I compute the image coordinates of the 3D point?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found at: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera Have a look at the script provided.