# How to project a point from 3D to 2D in blender?

Tags: camera

I know how to obtain the 4x4 projection matrix of the camera in Blender, but it seems its format is different from the standard camera projection matrices. I would appreciate it if someone explains how I can project a 3D point to 2D (image coordinates) using that projection matrix.

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-find-image-coordinates-of-the-rendered-vertex

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know how projection_matrix in the camera object works. In that question, they use world_to_camera_view.

Comment: did you read the answers?

Comment: read my answer to the question @zeffii refers to. its a relatively newer one, you missed it.

Comment: see also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera/38210