# How to calculate the transformation from the pivot point to each stereo camera

Tags: camera, transforms, stereoscopy

I checked the API documentation and [this related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81100/stereo-camera-extrinsic-parameter), and it looks like there is no easy way to get the pose of both the left-stereo and right-stereo cameras. So, I think the only solution is to calculate the transformation by ourselves. I will propose a solution myself but feel free to add your own to the answers if you know a better/simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Stereoscopy in ON (`bpy.context.scene.render.use_multiview = True`). No matter how you change the stereoscopy parameters (`Mode`, `Interocular Distance`, `Pivot`, ...), the `world_coordinates` of the camera are always the same, which can be obtained using `C.scene.camera.matrix_world`. So my first question was what is `camera.matrix_world` pose representing in a stereo setup?

A: I made some tests and I found that it always corresponds to the pose of the Pivot point. So if `Pivot = Left` it corresponds to the left camera, `Pivot = Right` to the right camera, and `Pivot = Centre` it corresponds to **neither of the cameras**, but the point in the middle!

For simplification, I will assume that we only care about the `Pivot = Left` scenario. Also, here I will assume that we are using the computer vision axis, with the Z outwards the camera. Since I am in the `Pivot = Left` scenario, I can convert the `C.scene.camera.matrix_world` into the extrinsic of the Left camera (using @rfabbri [method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera)). Note that if we were in the scenario of `Pivot = Centre`, we would need to calculate two transformations, from pivot to left-stereo and from pivot to right-stereo.

### `Pivot = Left`

**Stereo mode 1 - Parallel**

In this mode, it is easy to calculate the transformation, since it corresponds to a single translation that depends on the `stereo.interocular_distance`.

[image]

**Stereo mode 2 - Toe-in**

In this mode, in addition to the `interocular_distance` we rotate the non-pivot cameras, in this case, the right camera only. What I imagined it would be something like in the image below. However, I made a test, with a small sphere 10 [m] away from the pivot (in this case the left camera), with a `convergence_distance = 10` [m] and `interocular_distance = 10` [m]. With these values the centre of the sphere does not align on the two stereo images, so the set-up below is wrong.

[image]

Experiment:

[image]

**Stereo mode 3 - Off-Axis**

The off-axis currently I don't understand how it works.
I think here it is not only a geometrical transformation, but they also change the intrinsic matrix of the non-pivot camera, since they mention shifts in the documentation.

Does anyone understand how the **Toe-in** or **Off-Axis** work in Blender? Specifically, I am interested in their geometric models.

I will edit the answer once I find out more information.