# Homography between two planes with rotation and translation

Tags: camera, transforms, coordinates

I generated two camera views using Blender with rotation and translation.
Now I want to know how to compute homography between camera view A to B?

I found how to compute homography for rotation only from [opencv tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#tutorial_homography_Demo5) and [blender stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera/38210#38210) but as I mentioned only rotation is considered.