# What does the @-operator do?

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out what the @ in the following code does:

```
T_world2bcam = -1*R_world2bcam @ cam.location
```

where `R_world2bcam` is a 3x3 Matrix and `cam.location` is a Vector.

The code is from [this blender answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38210).

I have searched for this in the python docs, numpy docs, blender docs but was not able to find anything. Please excuse me, if this is a dumb answer, but I'm quite frustrated not being able to find anything about that ominous @.

Comment: In this case it's matrix-vector multiplication. It also does matrix-matrix multiplication and quaternion-quaternion multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me introduce you to [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) titled "*A dedicated infix operator for matrix multiplication*".  Introduced in 2014 and available in Python since version 3.5, the `@` operator is, as [scurest](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/88681/scurest) mentioned in a comment, a

> binary operator to be used for matrix multiplication

In math, you can multiply any two matrices $X$ and $Y$ provided that the second dimension of $X$ is the same as the first dimension of $Y$, that is, so long as $X$ is an $m$ x $n$ matrix and $Y$ is an $n$ x $o$ matrix.  The result will be a $m$ x $o$ matrix.  In math this is represented usually with the simple multiply operator $X *  Y$ but for reasons described in PEP 465, it was decided to adopt the `@` character in Python to distinguish matrix multiply, which is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), from scaler multiply, which in the case of two scalers is commutative.