# blender camera from 3x4 matrix

Tags: rendering, camera, import, tracking, coordinates

In computer vision, the transformation from 3D world coordinates to pixel coordinates is often represented by a 3x4 (3 rows by 4 cols) matrix P as detailed below. Given P I need code to return a camera in Blender.

This is the inverse of my previous question [3x4 camera matrix from blender camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera)

## Context where this shows up

This is useful for e.g. Augmented reality where 3x4 cameras are computed from real imagery using computer vision / structure from motion algorithms which are then used in CG to render registered synthetic models. Right now I want to employ multiple real images to be used as multiview reference for detailed 3D modeling.

## Some Details

An image pixel $(u,v)$ is generated from world $(x,y,z)$ coordinates through a 3x4 matrix using projective coordinates:

$$kx = PX$$

where $k$ is a constant, $x = (u,v,1)^t$, $X = (X,Y,Z,W)^t$, $P$ can be decomposed as

$$P=K[I|0] \begin{bmatrix}
R & T\\
0^\text{T} & 1
\end{bmatrix} = K[R|T]$$

and $K$ can be decomposed as

$$K=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_u & s & u_o\\
0 & \alpha_v & v_o\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

given that:

$$f=\text{focal length}$$
$$\alpha_u=\frac{f\times u\text{ pixels}}{\text{unit length}}=\frac{f}{\text{width of a pixel in world units}}$$
$$\alpha_v=\frac{f\times y\text{ pixels}}{\text{unit length}}=\frac{f}{\text{height of a pixel in world units}}$$
$$u_o=u\text{ coordinate of principle point}$$
$$v_o=v\text{ coordinate of principle point}$$
$$s_\theta=\text{skew factor}$$

I need to generate a Blender camera from this.

## Preliminary Research

I could certainly detail this up further in terms of all the coordinate systems and work out the solution myself if need be, but I'm looking to reuse well-tested shared code.

Libmv conversion code from internal to blender camera: libmv/src/ui/tvr/tvr_document.h

Directly related to: 
[What is blender's camera projection matrix model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/what-is-blenders-camera-projection-matrix-model)
[3x4 camera matrix from blender camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera)

Other related questions: 
[How can I get the camera's projection matrix?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/how-can-i-get-the-cameras-projection-matrix),
[How to find image coordinates of the rendered vertex?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-find-image-coordinates-of-the-rendered-vertex/884#884)

Comment: I just converted the images in this post to MathJax. It appears that there were some typos in the original images ($s$ vs $s_\theta$, and $f\times u$ vs $f\times y$). If you could put in the correct variables, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the function get_blender_camera_from_3x4_P to do this, listed below.

```
    # Input: P 3x4 numpy matrix
    # Output: K, R, T such that P = K*[R | T], det(R) positive and K has positive diagonal
    #
    # Reference implementations: 
    #   - Oxford's visual geometry group matlab toolbox 
    #   - Scilab Image Processing toolbox
    def KRT_from_P(P):
        N = 3
        H = P[:,0:N]  # if not numpy,  H = P.to_3x3()

        [K,R] = rf_rq(H)

        K /= K[-1,-1]

        # from http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/
        # make the diagonal of K positive
        sg = numpy.diag(numpy.sign(numpy.diag(K)))

        K = K * sg
        R = sg * R
        # det(R) negative, just invert; the proj equation remains same:
        if (numpy.linalg.det(R) < 0):
           R = -R
        # C = -H\P[:,-1]
        C = numpy.linalg.lstsq(-H, P[:,-1])[0]
        T = -R*C
        return K, R, T

    # RQ decomposition of a numpy matrix, using only libs that already come with
    # blender by default
    #
    # Author: Ricardo Fabbri
    # Reference implementations: 
    #   Oxford's visual geometry group matlab toolbox 
    #   Scilab Image Processing toolbox
    #
    # Input: 3x4 numpy matrix P
    # Returns: numpy matrices r,q
    def rf_rq(P):
        P = P.T
        # numpy only provides qr. Scipy has rq but doesn't ship with blender
        q, r = numpy.linalg.qr(P[ ::-1, ::-1], 'complete')
        q = q.T
        q = q[ ::-1, ::-1]
        r = r.T
        r = r[ ::-1, ::-1]

        if (numpy.linalg.det(q) < 0):
            r[:,0] *= -1
            q[0,:] *= -1
        return r, q

    # Creates a blender camera consistent with a given 3x4 computer vision P matrix
    # Run this in Object Mode
    # scale: resolution scale percentage as in GUI, known a priori
    # P: numpy 3x4
    def get_blender_camera_from_3x4_P(P, scale):
        # get krt
        K, R_world2cv, T_world2cv = KRT_from_P(numpy.matrix(P))

        scene = bpy.context.scene
        sensor_width_in_mm = K[1,1]*K[0,2] / (K[0,0]*K[1,2])
        sensor_height_in_mm = 1  # doesn't matter
        resolution_x_in_px = K[0,2]*2  # principal point assumed at the center
        resolution_y_in_px = K[1,2]*2  # principal point assumed at the center

        s_u = resolution_x_in_px / sensor_width_in_mm
        s_v = resolution_y_in_px / sensor_height_in_mm
        # TODO include aspect ratio
        f_in_mm = K[0,0] / s_u
        # recover original resolution
        scene.render.resolution_x = resolution_x_in_px / scale
        scene.render.resolution_y = resolution_y_in_px / scale
        scene.render.resolution_percentage = scale * 100

        # Use this if the projection matrix follows the convention listed in my answer to
        # https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera
        R_bcam2cv = Matrix(
            ((1, 0,  0),
             (0, -1, 0),
             (0, 0, -1)))

        # Use this if the projection matrix follows the convention from e.g. the matlab calibration toolbox:
        # R_bcam2cv = Matrix(
        #     ((-1, 0,  0),
        #      (0, 1, 0),
        #      (0, 0, 1)))

        R_cv2world = R_world2cv.T
        rotation =  Matrix(R_cv2world.tolist()) * R_bcam2cv
        location = -R_cv2world * T_world2cv

        # create a new camera
        bpy.ops.object.add(
            type='CAMERA',
            location=location)
        ob = bpy.context.object
        ob.name = 'CamFrom3x4PObj'
        cam = ob.data
        cam.name = 'CamFrom3x4P'

        # Lens
        cam.type = 'PERSP'
        cam.lens = f_in_mm 
        cam.lens_unit = 'MILLIMETERS'
        cam.sensor_width  = sensor_width_in_mm
        ob.matrix_world = Matrix.Translation(location)*rotation.to_4x4()

        #     cam.shift_x = -0.05
        #     cam.shift_y = 0.1
        #     cam.clip_start = 10.0
        #     cam.clip_end = 250.0
        #     empty = bpy.data.objects.new('DofEmpty', None)
        #     empty.location = origin+Vector((0,10,0))
        #     cam.dof_object = empty

        # Display
        cam.show_name = True
        # Make this the current camera
        scene.camera = ob
        bpy.context.scene.update()

    def test2():
        P = Matrix([
        [2. ,  0. , - 10. ,   282.  ],
        [0. ,- 3. , - 14. ,   417.  ],
        [0. ,  0. , - 1.  , - 18.   ]
        ])
        # This test P was constructed as k*[r | t] where
        #     k = [2 0 10; 0 3 14; 0 0 1]
        #     r = [1 0 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 -1]
        #     t = [231 223 -18]
        # k, r, t = KRT_from_P(numpy.matrix(P))
        get_blender_camera_from_3x4_P(P, 1)
```

## Tests

- I got an image with known 3x4 projection matrix P. This can be from a computer vision dataset (usually following the conventions of the Matlab camera calibration toolbox), tracked set, or by generating P from a blender camera as in [3x4 camera matrix from blender camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera)
- I ran the above algorithm for such P, obtaining a camera in Blender.
- The dataset I tested with has 3D reconstruction data as well
- Numpad 0 gives the camera view. I confirmed that it looks like the photo
- By adding a background image to the camera, I noticed that the 3D model projection is spot-on.

## Remarks

- This code is meant as a basis for a general solution. Modify this if you follow different conventions.
- Only unit aspect ratio (render option) is supported for now.
- The camera representation might sometimes look odd, but the only thing that matters is that it generates the right image.