# Camera projection matrix is always the same

Tags: python, camera, matrix, project

I wrote a simple python script to render a scene from different points of view. For each rendered image i also need to save the projection matrix of the camera that took the picture.

I try to get the projection matrix with **calc_matrix_camera()**, but it seems that even if i change the location/orientation of the camera the resulting matrix is always the same. Is the matrix returned by calc_matrix_camera an intrinsic matrix? Is it premultiplied with the extrinsic matrix? Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I am running the script via command line.

Here's the code i use to get the projection matrix:

```
for step in range(0, steps):
        radians = np.radians(step * (angle / steps))
        subject.location = (250 * np.cos(radians), 250 * np.sin(radians) , 150)
        look_at(subject, (0,0,100))
        dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get() 
        dg.update()
        projection_mat = bpy.context.scene.camera.calc_matrix_camera(
                dg,       #bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph,#
                x=bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x,
                y=bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y,
                scale_x=bpy.context.scene.render.pixel_aspect_x,
                scale_y=bpy.context.scene.render.pixel_aspect_y
                )
```

Comment: Hello ! This seems to be a limitation of using blender from the command line, please refer to the comments of this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50507/86891

Comment: Also this looks like it should answer your question https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86570/86891

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot. Unfortunately it seems that getting the depsgraph as `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].view_layers["View Layer"].depsgraph` does not solve the problem for me.