# bpy: Defining object location in view coordinates using the projection matrix

Tags: python, scripting, camera

I want to scatter multiple objects inside the view frustum of the active camera. In theory it is easy:

1. Generate a random 3D Vector with values in [0..1]
2. Read the projection and camera matrices of the camera
3. Invert them and multiply them with the vector from step 1
4. Set the objects position to the result

But in praxis this just seems impossible. Reading the transform matrices is a challenge in itself, but with some adjustments an answer from an [older question regarding the projection matrix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/how-can-i-get-the-cameras-projection-matrix) seems to work.

```
camera_to_world = camera.matrix_world
view_to_camera = camera.calc_matrix_camera(
    bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(),
    x = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x,
    y = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y,
    scale_x = bpy.context.scene.render.pixel_aspect_x,
    scale_y = bpy.context.scene.render.pixel_aspect_y)
```

Transforming the point should be straightforward, assuming the order is correct. The "camera_to_world" we read is already the right direction, saving us one inverse.

```
point_camera = np.append(point_view,1) @ projection_matrix.inverted()
point_world = point_camera @ modelview_matrix
obj.location = point_world
```

However, the end result does not look pretty:
[image: The scattered points, outside of the frustum and weirdly aligned]
What am i missing here? There are 31 other ways to combine the matrices, vectors and inverse, but i don't think that the issue lies there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of operations was right, but i was missing a normalization step after applying the inverse projection matrix - the point (now in camera space) has to be divided by its w component.
The right way of transforming a point from screen coordinates (render, not viewport) to world coordinates is as follows:

```python
    #get inverse projection matrices
    inverse_camera_matrix = camera.matrix_world
    projection_matrix = camera.calc_matrix_camera(
        bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(),
        x = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x,
        y = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y)
    inverse_projection_matrix = projection_matrix.inverted()
    
    #project from view to camera space
    point_camera = inverse_projection_matrix @ point_view
    
    #normalize
    point_camera.x /= point_camera.w
    point_camera.y /= point_camera.w
    point_camera.z /= point_camera.w
    point_camera.w = 1
    
    #project from camera to world space
    point_world = inverse_camera_matrix @ point_camera
```