# Why are straight lines sloping in render?

Tags: rendering, camera

Why are the walls in my architectural renders sloping and how do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5183/599

Answer (score 17):

The lens shift controls on the camera exist in Blender precisely to solve this problem. Photographers use tilt-shift lenses to do the same thing.

Rather than rotating the camera upwards to the building, you can keep it pointing straight ahead, and increase the camera Y shift. This will preserve straight vertical lines.

A good visualization of that is here:
http://digitized-life.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/blender-26.html

Answer (score 4):

All of the vertical lines are sloping towards a vanishing point because you are looking up at the building. It's called 3-point perspective. It's natural, so it's not out of place or wrong. But since you have everything above the horizon line, 3-point perspective will be pretty obvious. If you don't like it, try making the camera face the building dead on without any up or down tilt; that would make it more 2-point perspective.