# Need help with perspective matching

Tags: modeling, camera

I love this painting by Ed Ruscha, and wanted to created a 3D tribute to it.

[image: Standard by Ed Ruscha]

The idea seemed simple enough, but as I set out to do it, I had a lot of trouble getting the perspective to match. I even tried to using the BLAM add-on, which got me close, but I still can't seem to get the z axis lines of a rectangular mesh to line up with the painting. See the screen shot below.

[image: Screen shot]

Am I missing something obvious? or could it be that this painting is somehow an illusion, and impossible realistically model in 3D?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: interesting painting btw!

Comment: It's perfect for matching. Ed did a bang on job with the perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can align this pretty well. The picture below is a rough result but it matches somewhat accurately.

[image]

From Haunt's trick bag:

Put the camera parallel to the ground. Switch on center guides in the camera settings.

Use your image as background image for the camera and shift it so that the floor rests with the center line.

Place a cube, also parallel to the ground, with its corner on the upper front corner of the roof. Distance doesn't matter too much. Put the cube's origin on this corner.

Rotate the cube around the z axis to roughly fit the angle. you can lock y and x to prevent errors. But the cube probably won't fit right away.

[image]

This result means, the focal length is too small since distortion is too strong.

Now adjust the focal length of the camera. I did this by animating it and switching frames with the arrow key. Re-align and re-rotate the cube around z until it matches perfectly.

When cube rotation and focal length match up, parent the camera to the cube and reset the cube's rotation.

Now you can freely move and extrude along the main axes and build your scene.

To match the pillars, finish the roof and place the top of the pillars at the exact height of the roof so it touches the underside in front view. Back in Camera View, move the pillar with the Z-axis excluded: <kbd>G</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

At last, you need to tilt your camera up so you can make the image smaller and the floor rest at the bottom of your image.

Comment: Thanks so much @Haunt_House, this really helps me so much.

Comment: @PatrickKrabeepetcharat One is glad to be of service (I added a tip on how to place the pillars)

Answer (score 4):

In the reference painting, the Z axis is orthogonal while the X and Y are perspective (two point perspective):

[How to make a two-point perspective render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5183/how-to-make-a-two-point-perspective-render)

The trick is to leave your camera flat, i.e. without any angle up or down then use the Shift Y to frame the shot.

[image]

Comment: also you may have to tweak the camera (rendering) aspect ratio to match the painting

Comment: Using the shift value is a cool trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Blam addon, but:

Bacause of Blam is NOT recontructing camera shift you have to set it up your self. After using Blam, manual shift and some tweeking I get this:
[image: reconstruction result]
[image]

Comment: Quoting Patrick: " I even tried to using the BLAM add-on"...third line from the top.

Comment: I'll try it too... moment... :)

Comment: See the edited answer...

Comment: I do. I see a youtube video that could go away any second, mutilating your otherwise very useful answer.