# Can camera show perspective VP lines?

Tags: 3d-view

Hey all is it possible to have blender not only show the grid
but the persp lines of the VP in the camera view

like this
https://i2.wp.com/www.thedrawingwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Two-Point-perspective-grid.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a two-point perspective render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5183/how-to-make-a-two-point-perspective-render)

Comment: check this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5183/how-to-make-a-two-point-perspective-render

Comment: No thats not what i mean, I want to see the guidelines like in the photo i posted

Comment: Any ideas guys?